# Google Calendar API FreeBusy Access Using Service Account

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

We have built an application that is attempting to use a Service Account to access the google Calendar API. We manage the application ourselves, but the calendars we are trying to access are on a separate GSuite account. We have had the GSuite admin follow the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) to allow access to our app based on client ID and the auth scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly."

Now when using the service account to attempt to access user calendar data, I'm a bit confused about how to properly format the request. Specifically, if I don't include a "sub" parameter, the request works in the sense that I am granted a token and I'm able to proceed to make a subsequent request to access calendars. However in that subsequent request, I am returned with errors on users calendars indicating not found i.e. I don't have access. Below is the request:

```
String jwtClaimset = '{'+
                          '"iss":"xxxxx@service-account.com",'+
                          '"sub":"xxxxxx@xxxx.com",'+
                          '"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",'+
                          '"aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",'+
                          '"exp":'+expTime+','+
                          '"iat":'+requestTime+
                            '}';
```

However, then if I include a specific email/username from the GSuite account to "impersonate", I am not able to request the token at all, I'm presented with the below error:

> "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."

So my question is, do I need the sub parameter to access any of the users calendars in the GSuite and if so do you know why that error is being presented?

Answer (score 2):

And I have no idea what happened maybe it just took time for the GSuite permissions/access to update but now this is working.

For note, we are using the sub parameter and its working using that (as we suspected we needed).

Comment: Hi George. I am trying to write some APIs in NodeJs which can list events of users and create events in their calendars. Our organization's mail account and the calendar is on gsuite. I have tried googleapis package for nodejs with JWT based authentication, but it  is not showing any events for the primary user. Not sure how the service account credentials are going to impersonate other user accounts. Could you please guide me through the process to achieve this ?